# Analyzing stability of equilibrium points in a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let us consider the dynamical system

\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}&=\frac{(a-x)}{b} -z-u, \\
\dot{y}&=x-c y, \\
\dot{z}&=x-y, \\
\dot{u}&=x-1
\end{aligned},
where $a,b,c$ are parameters
We can observe that the equilibrium point of the system is of the form $(x, y,z, u) = (1,1,\frac{a-1}{b}-t,t)$, where $t \in \Bbb{R}$. So here we have infinite number of equilibrium points depending on $t$. The equilibrium points exists only when $c=1$.

For the stability of the equilibrium points, I got the characteristic equation to be
$P(\lambda) = \lambda^{4} + \lambda^{3}(c + \frac{1}{b}) + \lambda^{2}(2-\frac{c}{b})+\lambda(2c-1)  =0$ implying one eigenvalue is zero.

For stability we need all real parts of four eigenvalues to be less than zero. I am thinking how to proceed from here?

I am thinking if there exists any stable equilibrium point or they are all unstable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\dot y = x - cy$ implies that $c = 1$, then the characteristic polynomial is

$$\lambda (\lambda ^3+\left(1+\frac{1}{b}\right)\,\lambda ^2+\left(2+\frac{1}{b}\right)\,\lambda +1)$$

Since there is a single root equal $0$ the system can only be at most marginally stable

Using the Routh table:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2+1/b & 0\\ \hline
1+1/b& 1& 0\\ \hline
(1/b^2+3/b + 1) b/(b+1)& 0& 0\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
The condition for the system to be marginally stable is $1+1/b \geq 0$, $(1/b^2+3/b + 1) b/(b+1) \geq 0$. Consequently $b\in [\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2},-1]$. Then you need to check $b$ at the boundaries to make sure that there all imaginary roots are distinct

Comment: Any reference for the definition of marginally stable ?

Comment: Also i think there must one more row in the table?

Comment: @BAYMAX marginally stable means that the system given no disturbance will converge to an equilibrium, but it may not be the same equilibrium before being disturbed. You can find a [more precise definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability#). For the routh table I only took the cubic part so only four rows

Comment: Okay, the system still has infinite number of equilibrium points? are we saying equilibrium points are marginally stable? or the system is marginally stable? what about stability of equilibrium points.. How can we conclude marginally stability if eigenvalue is zero?

Comment: @BAYMAX since the autonomous system is linear, the stability is applied to all equilibrium points. For a nonlinear autonomous system you would need to consider each equilibrium point. You must know about all eigenvalues to conclude whether a linear system is asymptotically stable, unstable or marginally stable. A linear system that has some eigenvalues lying on the imaginary axis is marginally stable if all those imaginary eigenvalues are distinct and that other eigenvalues lies in the left haft of the complex plane. Otherwise it's unstable